# Embedding webviews in tabs

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tabhost

I got my webview embedded but now I cannot make a back button for them because my webview is declared in the oncreate method and if i declare it in the class i get a force close.. here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(Twitter.this, "", 
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);


    WebView webview1 = new WebView(this);
    webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview1.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(pd));
    webview1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY) ;
```

When I use the code for a back button in webview, it does not read webview1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code doesn't go in xml at all.

Since each of the screens available from the tabs is its own activity, don't forget to add it to the manifest file (or it will force close). The code to manipulate these activities goes in their own file.

Notice from the tutorial where it says:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
```

The 'ArtistsActivity' there is a separate class with its own file. You'll want to create one of those, and give it its own layout.xml file as well (if you need one).

Comment: When I declare my webview variable outside of the oncreate method i get a force close, why is this? I need to do this so I can set my back button function.

Comment: What webview variable are you talking about?

Comment: WebView webview1;  if i declare it in my activity, my program force closes, but in the oncreate method it works. is there a way to declare that so I can use it in all of my classes?

Comment: If you'll post the code where you're trying to declare it, I'll take a look. Remember that you can only declare it once, ie, you can't say 

`WebView webview1`

... outside of onCreate and then 

    `WebView webview1 = new WebView(this);`

... in the onCreate. You'd put this in the onCreate. 

   `webview1 = new WebView(this);`

Comment: Thank you for the help Hydrangea, that seemed to do the trick. I had to just declare it with WebView webview1; and then remove the WebView from the code above.  Now is there a way to make the webview available to other classes so i can set the tabchangelistener and reload the webview when leaving the tab

Comment: Why do you want to reload the webview when leaving the tab? Changing the tab will close the activity.

Comment: My webviews have flash content on them and when switching tabs the flash music player overlaps the content on the new tab so refreshing the previous tab takes care of this issue.

Comment: Okay, so, you know how an Activity has an onCreate method? It also has  [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) and a few other lifecycle events you can override. Try handling it there. 

You can't manipulate an activity from another activity.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly the onPause() is what is called when I switch tabs? Since earlier you said changing the tab will close the activity? So if I put webview1.reload() in the onPause method it should handle correctly?

Comment: When I tried what I said above I get a force close.. do you need to use an onResume() method when using an onPause() method? Or was the above post a wrong assumption? I am so close to having my app work exactly how I want it to, I think this is the last tweak so thank you.

Comment: @Hydrangea I have one last question.. it also reloads the webpage when the screen locks and I do not want this to happen because I want them to be able to listen to the music while their phone screen is locked. Is there something else I can do when switching tabs, like force it to stop and not just pause on tab switches?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am the OP and this issue is solved I just needed to add super.onpause in my method, thanks for your time hydrangea

Comment: Since your original question had to do with where to declare the webview, and I answered it, would you mind checking the question as answered?

Comment: Yes, sorry I am new to stackoverflow. Can I direct you to my next question in that case? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212391/help-using-ontabchangelistener