# Help Using OnTabChangeListener

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have an app that is using 3 tabs and each has its own activity. There is also a main class that declares all the tab intents and such. My problem is that I need to use this in each individual activity:

```
 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if("TAB_1".equals(tabId)) {
           webview2.reload();

        }
        if("TAB_2".equals(tabId)) {
            webview2.reload();
               }
    }});
```

I cannot use this because tabHost cannot be resolved, is there a way to pass this through to each individual activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use that code in each activity, rather you use it in the main activity and reference the webview objects in each activity from there.